# Why I cannot add colours to my bar chart in Rstudio?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, bar-chart

I used the code below but it only shows charts with no color

```
gbar <- ggplot(data=episode_data, aes(x=season))
gbar + 
   geom_bar() +
   scale_fill_brewer(type = "seq", palette = 1, direction = 1, aesthetics = "fill")
```

[image]

Comment: `ggplot(data=episode_data, aes(x=season, fill = season))`

Answer (score 1):

As no data is provided, I will explain you two way to add color in a plot using demo data `iris`. You can set the aesthetic element `fill` in order to add some variable to fill your bars. The output of a code using that option would be next:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
#Data
data("iris")
#Example 1 color by species
iris %>% pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,fill=Species))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```

Output:

[image]

The second option would be directly enable `fill` option inside `geom_bar()` with some defined color like this:

```
#Examples 2 only one color
iris %>% pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',fill='cyan3')
```

Output:

[image]

For the code you added try this, and next time please include a sample of your data to reproduce your issue:

```
#Option 1
ggplot(data=episode_data, aes(x=season))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',fill='red')
#Option 2
ggplot(data=episode_data, aes(x=season,fill=factor(season)))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity')
```